# How to pre fill Windows Forms controls on form load event from Web API?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asp.net-web-api2

I have a solution with two projects: One web API and the other one is a Windows Forms application. In the Windows Forms application I send a get request to retrieve some data. So I have a method like this:

```
private async Task StartFillingEvent()
{
    var path = "api/Windows/GetEventNames/";
    List<EventItemDto> events = null;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        events = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<EventItemDto>>();
        var eventList = (from c in events
                            select new ListItemVm<Guid>()
                            {
                                Id = c.EventId,
                                Name = c.Title
                            }).ToList();

        eventsDrp.FillDropDownList<Guid>("Please choose one", eventList, null);
    }
}
```

which gets my data and in form_Load i call this method:

```
private void frmOnlineBadge_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartFillingEvent().Wait();
}
```

I traced my application it goes to web API and retrieves data to the Windows Forms application. But the application sleeps in the `if` statement. I have no knowledge of multi threading. My goal is to interact with the web API. I googled and i found lots of tutorials with windows console application not with Windows Forms. I checked my program with console application but I have to work with controls in Forms application.

How can I manage this data retrieval?

Comment: excuse me i didn't quite understand where your application stops working? is it after send your request into your web-api?

Comment: yes. it goes to web api method but never backed to windows project.

Comment: Do not use .Wait() in a winforms environment. Try: `private async void frmOnlineBadge_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await StartFillingEvent();
    }`

Comment: i tried but i get "System.NullReferenceException", But I retrieved data!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful when you wait on an `async` method. Since it is run on the same thread as you execute your `Wait`, you are running into a deadlock. The `async/await` multitasking is cooperative. That means the `await` is waiting for return of control from the caller. If the caller now calls `Wait` it will never return control.

The solution is to run your worker method in a task:

```
private void frmOnlineBadge_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => StartFillingEvent()).Wait();
}
```

This will wrap the task into a proxy that will run as a real task. As a consequence you have to modify the part where you fill your combo box:

```
Action fillAction = delegate() {
    eventsDrp.FillDropDownList<Guid>("Please choose one", eventList, null);
};
dropDownList.BeginInvoke(fillAction);
```

The reason is that since you run your operation in the background now, you have to make sure you execute the part where you access the UI in the UI thread. That is done with `Control.BeginInvoke`.

**Update:**

I initially wrote you should use `Control.Invoke`. That is wrong, because this method will block until the UI thread has executed the action to the end. Since the UI thread is waiting, this also causes a deadlock. So you you have to use `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: I tried your answer but this time application dies when invokes: "eventsDrp.Invoke(fillAction);"

Comment: @Afsaneh: Yes, you're right. The `Invoke` waits for the UI thread, which is the next deadlock. I edited my answer. The `BeginInvoke` won't wait.

Comment: this time i get System.NullReferenceException when it fills dropdownlist.

Comment: @Afsaneh: That is another error that you didn't see until now because your method was not executed. Check why that happens. Your problem of the question is solved.

Comment: @safe I traced my code it gets items before creating delegate.

Comment: @Afsaneh: Either your `eventsDrp` is `null` or your problem is within `FillDropDownList`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130425/discussion-between-afsaneh-and-sefe).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to start new task, which will start new thread, you don't need to use some "hacky invokes" workaround.

Extract retrieving data in the own asynchronous method, make `Form_Load` asynchronous and fill control with data in maintainable, readable and clean way.

```
private async Task<List<EventItemDto>> GetEventsAsync()
{
    var path = "api/Windows/GetEventNames/";
    var events = new List<EventItemDo>();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        events = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<EventItemDto>>();
    }

    return events;
}

private void FillWithEvents(List<EventItemDo> events)
{
    var eventList = events.Select(event => new ListItemVm<Guid>
                                 {
                                     Id = c.EventId,
                                     Name = c.Title
                                 }).ToList();

    eventsDrp.FillDropDownList<Guid>("Please choose one", eventList, null);
}
```

you need make eventhandler `async`.

```
private async void frmOnlineBadge_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var events = await GetEventsAsync();
    FillWithEvents(events);
}
```